# IllegalArgumentException on Collections.sort() method

Tags: java, comparator

I have comparator for strings, which are converted to date. When I pass this comparator to Collections.sort() method I get **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!**.

I have read some articles about this exception, but I don't really understand why this exception appears. Any idea ?

```
private SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");   

    Comparator<String> comparator = new Comparator<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                        if (o1 == null && o2 == null) {
                            return 0;
                        }
                        if (o1 == null) {
                            return 1;
                        }
                        if (o2 == null) {
                            return -1;
                        }
                        try {
                            Date first = sdf.parse(o1);
                            Date second = sdf.parse(o2);
                            return first.compareTo(second);
                        } catch (Exception ignored) {
                            return 0;
                        }
                    }
                };
```

Comment: your collection of strings may have bad format strings, what is the sample data your have in your List<String> ?

Comment: Please add the full stacktrace. what are the values of o1 and o2?

Comment: @Jens There is not problem in parsing dates, the problem is in logic of comparator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case an exception is thrown, you return 0. That means whenever any of the arguments cannot be parsed, both are considered equal. Think of this example:

```
a = "01/01/2015"
b = "01/01/2016"
c = "xxx"
```

Then you get

```
comparator.compare(a,c) = 0
comparator.compare(b,c) = 0
```

but

```
comparator.compare(a,b) != 0
```

Solution: Try parsing each of the Strings separately, and on exception use `null` like this:

private SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");

```
Comparator<String> comparator = new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        Date first;
        try {
            first = sdf.parse(o1);
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
            first = null;
        }
        Date second;
        try {
            second = sdf.parse(o2);
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
            second = null;
        }

        if (first == second) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (first == null) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (second == null) {
            return -1;
        }
        return first.compareTo(second);
    }
};
```

Comment: The [only `Objects.compare` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#compare-T-T-java.util.Comparator-) requires a comparator and besides that, it doesn’t provide a `null` policy as you seem to assume. But the way the OP already handles `null`s in his original code is sufficient.

Comment: @holger yes for your first objection. But the second does not apply. It's not about passing null but the exception handling that causes the problem. Will update my answer when i'm home. The current answer is perhaps a little too unprecise.

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood me. Using your solution, excluding the last line, followed by how the OP’s code handled `null` (the three `if` statements) and finally `return first.compareTo(second);` will work.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your `try catch` block.

Even if 1 of the dates is not parsable, you are returning `0` (which means the objects are equal).

Now let's take this condition.

```
str1 = "invalid";
str2 = "10/10/2015"; //Consider this to be valid format.
str3 = "12/10/2015";
```

Now, let's run over the comparisons,

1. compare **str1** and **str2**: Returns `0` (which means equal)
2. compare **str1** and **str3**: Returns `0` (which means equal)

Which means, when you compare **str2** and **str3**, then should be `equal`. (`A=B` and `A=C` means `B=C`).

But when it compares, it returns a negative number. Hence the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Nice. You problem is actually not that hard... Imagine you have three Strings...

`Date 1 = correct date string for "Today"
Date 2 = correct date string for "Tomorrow"
Date 3 = XYZ (an non-correct date String that will throw an exception when parsed)`

`Date 1 < Date 2, obviously.
Date 2 > Date 1, also obvious, works fine`

But now the magic trick/problem:

`Date 3 == Date 1 - because of your exception handling`

AND

`Date 3 == Date 2 - also because of that (for both you will return 0).`

So there is a Date that is EQUAL to both 1 and 2, but 1 and 2 are NOT equal.

Ask yourself, where would you place Date 3 in your list? It has to be on the same "position" as Date 1 (because it is compared with == 0) AND on the same "position" as Date 2 (again, it compares with == 0 with that). BUT Date 1 and Date 2 are NOT on the same position. This is impossible, thus you are getting your "Comparison method violates its general contract!." exception.

Comment: I understood, really not hard. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your collection of Strings probably has unparsable dates. This leads to returning 0 in situations where it doesn't make sense.

```
String a = "badString";
String b = "20/12/2012 12:13";
String c = "20/12/2015 13:14";
```

b is smaller than c and c is greater than b. b and c are thus not equal. But your function says they are both equal to String a! That makes no sense and it is impossible for `Collections.sort` to sort correctly.

b needs to be before c, c needs to be after b but a needs to be right next to b AND c.

A better way to handle your comparator would be to filter the List of Strings first, so that you're only comparing valid dates. Your function can then just throw a RuntimeException about still not being able to parse Dates.

Answer (score 0):

The sorting algorithm used by java.util.Arrays.sort and (indirectly) by java.util.Collections.sort has been replaced. The new sort implementation may throw an IllegalArgumentException if it detects a Comparable that violates the Comparable contract. The previous implementation silently ignored such a situation. If the previous behavior is desired, you can use the new system property, java.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort, to restore previous mergesort behavior

Comment: Why would you just silently ignore errors in your program? That does not seem like a good solution.