# How to reorder Stream of CompletableFutures?

Tags: java, java-stream, completable-future

I deal with Streams of CompletableFutures. These take different times to complete. Those taking longer block stream processing while others might already have completed (and I know about Parallel Streams)

Therefore I would like to reorder items in a Stream (e.g. with a buffer) to move completed Futures ahead.

For example, this code blocks stream processing if one getUser call takes long

```
public static Boolean isValid(User user) { ... }

emails.stream()
   // not using ::
   // getUser() returns CompletableFuture<User>
  .map( e -> getUser(e))
  // this line blocks Stream processing
  .filter( userF -> isValid( userF.get()) )
  .map( f -> f.thenApply(User::getName))
```

and I would like to have something like

```
emails.stream()
   .map( e -> getUser(e))
   // this moves Futures into a bounded buffer
   // and puts those finished first
   // like CompletionService [1]
   // and returns a Stream again
   .collect(FutureReorderer.collector())
   // this is not the same Stream but
   // the one created by FutureReorderer.collector()
   .filter( userF -> isValid( userF.get()) )
   .map( f -> f.thenApply(User::getName))
```

[1] For example CompletionService https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html returns completed tasks when calling take() and blocks otherwise. But CompletionService does not take futures, would one need to do cs.sumbit( () -> f.get() ) ?

How would I do that?

[Edit]

1. Changed example to include filter()
2. Added comment
3. Added CompletionService link

Comment: Why not using `CompletableFuture::thenApplyAsync`?

Comment: Changed example to add filter() to make it clearer.

Comment: Why don't try ..stream.parallel()...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having more context would definitely help in tailoring the answer - I have a feeling that problem is somewhere else and can be solved in an easier way.

But if your question is how to somehow keep completed futures at the beginning, there are few options:

---

**Sorting the `Stream` using a custom `Comparator`:**

```
.sorted(Comparator.comparing(f -> !f.isDone()))
```

Keep in mind that `isDone` returns true not only when a future completes successfully.

---

**Storing futures in a `PriorityQueue`**

```
PriorityQueue<CompletableFuture<String>> queue
 = new PriorityQueue<>(Comparator.comparing(f -> !f.isDone()));
```

when polling elements, the queue will be returning elements according to their provided ordering.

Here it is in action:

```
PriorityQueue<CompletableFuture<String>> queue
 = new PriorityQueue<>(Comparator.comparing(f -> !f.isDone()));

queue.add(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {  }

    return "42";
}));

queue.add(CompletableFuture.completedFuture("completed"));

queue.poll(); // "completed"
queue.poll(); // still going on
```

It's important to remember that if you do want to convert `PriorityQueue` to `Stream`, you can't do this simply using `stream()` - this will not preserve the priority order.

This is the right way to go:

```
Stream.generate(queue::poll).limit(queue.size())
```

Comment: Using such a filter, wouldn't it be possible for a given Future object F to be in state "in progress" when being compared early on, and in state "completed" when being compared later on ? I think I can remember the default sorting in Java not liking when such stuff happens (e.g. it fails with IllegalState), like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31556639/illegalargumentexception-on-collections-sort-method. But maybe my recollection is not exact, and this can only happen on badly designed comparison algorithms...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm not sure the sorted would work, because when sorted() is called, most Futures will not have completed, and the stream is not sorted. About the PriorityQueue: So the collector would add to the PriorityQueue? How would one transform the priority queue into a Stream again?

Comment: @StephanSchmidt streams are non-reusable iterators so you will always need to keep creating new instances to get an up-to-date snapshot -  It's possible to create a Stream from the PriorityQueue but it's pretty much the same problem

Comment: @GPI yes, it's possible but this will always be the case because computations take non-zero time and in this time some other computation might complete

Comment: @GrzegorzPiwowarek Thanks, yes I understand about the new instances. If I understand it right, PriorityQueue is kind of best-effort. The queue is sorted upon construction/insertion and poll() when called returns completed Futures first, and if there are no more completed Futures would return those uncompleted at the time of queue construction/when added.

Comment: @GrzegorzPiwowarek  of course, thanks. Nevertheless, the possibility of the sort not being perfect (which in context is understandable), and a failure with an exception have different consequences. Thus, my question. I'll test this if I get time...

Answer (score -1):

I assume the requirements in OP is execute `getUser` concurrently and process the result Futures by completion order. Here is solution by `ExecutorCompletionService`:

```
final CompletionService<User> ecs = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(executor);

emails.stream().map(e -> ecs.submit(() -> getUser(e).get()))
    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), fs -> fs.stream())) // collect the future list for concurrent execution
    .map(f -> {
            try {
                return ecs.take().get();
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        })
    .filter(u -> isValid(u)).map(User::getName)... //TODO;
```

Or:

```
final BlockingQueue<Future<User>> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(emails.size());
final CompletionService<User> ecs = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(executor, queue);        
emails.stream().forEach(e -> ecs.submit(() -> getUser(e).get()));

IntStream.range(0, emails.size())
    .mapToObj(i -> {
            try {
                return queue.poll().get();
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        })
    .filter(u -> isValid(u)).map(User::getName);
```

It's simple but not straightforward.

Comment: Are you using ECS for unwrapping already existing future instances? Why in the first example are you collecting everything to list only to convert it back to stream again? That's not simple - that's a mess

Comment: @GrzegorzPiwowarek the collecting is concurrent execution. otherwise getUser is only executed asyn but not concurrent

Comment: he has already Future instances and there is a clear indication that those operations are already running concurrently

Comment: the first stream code in OP: ...map( e -> getUser(e)).filter( userF -> isValid( userF.get())...getUser only executed one by one asynchronously. I think that's why he want: ..collect(FutureReorderer.collector())... I guess you're better to look into the question/answers again, the sort in your answer doesn't resolve any problem, if i understand the OP correctly.

Comment: @123-xys he already has those processes running, he wants to iterate over all of them and use a blocking get probably. In this case, it makes sense to process already completed futures before blocking on something

Comment: @GrzegorzPiwowarek Where? I guess you missed the point:  the getUser(I think it's probably a db/network call) in the first stream in OP only run one by one asynchronously, not in concurrent. if there are 100 emails, that means the getUser will be called 100 times sequentially. it will take long time to complete 100 db/network calls. The second stream is something he wants. There are two things to do: running getUser concurrently, it also can be done by .parallel(); The second thing, process the futures by the completion order.  ExecutorCompletionService is perfect for those two requirements.

Comment: For example: if he just want the first result as soon as possible, not to wait for all futures are completed: it can be: stream()....map(User::getName).findAny();